# how to pass array as an parameter using routing in angular 4

Tags: json, angular, angular-routing

I am working on an angular project I want pass an array object as an parameter to another page through rouuting my function is as follows

```
Goto(item)
{

    console.log(item.numtopics);
    this.router.navigate(['/numbersystem'],  { queryParams: item.numtopics});

}
```

and getting the data as follows

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe( param => {


        console.log(param);
    });

    }
```

but in console I am getting data like this

```
{0: "[object Object]", 1: "[object Object]", 2: "[object Object]"}
```

I am not getting the array data properly

any help.
Thank You !!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get this passed array, you should use:

```
console.log(param.numtopics)
```

or you can also pass array like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/numbersystem'],  { queryParams: item.numtopics});
```

and then you can get this array like you tried:

```
console.log(param)
```

Comment: I have also done that but its its giving same data as an object.

Comment: @HarshaKadwe: queryParams is object. so you can pass { queryParams: { parameterName:  item.numtopics } } and further detail just go throw  documentation https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Comment: i have done also edited my question its giving me same error.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the official [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters), how queryParams are passed.

The reason why you get data like `{0: "[object Object]", 1: "[object Object]", 2: "[object Object]"}` is because it's an object.

Try passing `JSON.stringify(item.numtopics)` to the queryparams. This will pass a string to the queryParams. Also you can mention the **NAME** of the query(Refer Doc).  For exapmle :

```
https://www.yourdomain.com/search?NAME=stringifiedString
```

Before you pass the stringified array you may want to encrypt the data so you can use some encryption algorithm. Thereafter, in the component where you retrieve the params you can again use `JSON.parse(paramsData)` to get array back from the string.

In case if you've used encryption, you should decrypt first and then use JSON.parse()